# How can I display the total number of records a table holds(the count) in a view by passing the count value in the "return view method"

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, model-view-controller, razor

How can I display the total number of records a table holds(the count). I would like to display the count in a view so I am trying to pass the count as a parameter on return view but I get an error saying cannot convert string to int. I am pretty sure there is a smarter way to do this. I have tried converting the int value using toString() but I still get syntax erros thereafter. I have placed both my controller and view below. Notice what I am trying to do in my controller  in the return view method I am trying to insert the count but I get an error that says
cannot convert from int? to string

**Controller**

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Web.Http;
    using System.Configuration;
    using PagedList;

    namespace App.Web.Controllers
    {
        public class DisplayUploadedFileController : Controller
        {
            private EntitiesModel db = new EntitiesModel();

            public ActionResult DisplayUploadedFileContents(int? id, int? page, int? totalCount)
            {

                var vm = new dbclients_invalidEmailsVM();
                vm.UploadId = id ?? default(int);
                if (page == null)
                {
                    page = 1;
                }
                int pageSize = 10;
                int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

                var rows = from myRow in db.tbl_dataTable
                           select myRow;
                totalCount = rows.Count();

                return View(db.tbl_dataTable.OrderByDescending(r => r.ClientId).Where(r => r.UploadId == id).ToList().ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize), totalCount);

            }
        }

}
```

**View**

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<App.Web.marketingdbclients_dataTable>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="pagination.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:50px;">

        <table class="table" id="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    First Name
                </th>

                <th>
                    Last Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Cell1
                </th>
                <th>
                    Email1
                </th>

                <th>
                    Company
                </th>
                <th>
                    Job Title
                </th>
                <th>
                    Province
                </th>

                <th>
                    Source
                </th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cell1)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email1)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobTitle)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhysicalProvince)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Source)
                    </td>



                </tr>
            }

        </table>
        </br>
        Number of Records  @Model.Count()<br />

        Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("DisplayUploadedFileContents", new { uploadId = Model.First().UploadId, page }))
    </div>
</body>
</html>


My Table Represented as a model

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    namespace App.Web
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        public partial class marketingdbclients_dataTable
        {
            public int ClientDataId { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> ClientId { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> UploadId { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string MiddleName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string IdentificationNumber { get; set; }
            public string RaceId { get; set; }
            public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
            public string Age { get; set; }
            public string TitleTypeId { get; set; }
            public string GenderTypeId { get; set; }
            public string Nationality { get; set; }
            public string PhysicalCountry { get; set; }
            public string PhysicalProvince { get; set; }
            public string PhysicalCity { get; set; }
            public string Area { get; set; }
            public string HighestQualification { get; set; }
            public string CurrentQualification { get; set; }
            public string PhysicalAddress { get; set; }
            public string PostalAddress { get; set; }
            public string Cell1 { get; set; }
            public string Cell2 { get; set; }
            public string Cell3 { get; set; }
            public string Cell4 { get; set; }
            public string Work1 { get; set; }
            public string Work2 { get; set; }
            public string Work3 { get; set; }
            public string Work4 { get; set; }
            public string Home1 { get; set; }
            public string Home2 { get; set; }
            public string Home3 { get; set; }
            public string Home4 { get; set; }
            public string LSMGroup { get; set; }
            public string Municipality { get; set; }
            public string Crediting_Rating { get; set; }
            public string Email1 { get; set; }
            public string Email2 { get; set; }
            public string Email3 { get; set; }
            public string Email4 { get; set; }
            public string Income { get; set; }
            public string Company { get; set; }
            public string Industry { get; set; }
            public string JobTitle { get; set; }
            public string LeadStage { get; set; }
            public string ReggieNumber { get; set; }
            public string Source { get; set; }
            public System.DateTime DateInserted { get; set; }
            //public int totalEntriesCount { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use ViewBag.Count = totalCount; Also there is good way to paging. You can find in Nuget : DataTables.AspNet.Mvc5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create a new ViewModel class and store your two inputs like so:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<marketingdbclients_dataTable> marketingdbclients_dataTables { get; set; }
    public int totalCount { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.marketingdbclients_dataTables = new List<marketingdbclients_dataTable>();
        this.totalCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Controller file should be

```
public ActionResult DisplayUploadedFileContents(int? id, int? page, int? totalCount)
{
     var vm = new dbclients_invalidEmailsVM();
     vm.UploadId = id ?? default(int);
     if (page == null)
     {
        page = 1;
     }
     int pageSize = 10;
     int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);   
     var rows = from myRow in db.tbl_dataTable
                select myRow;
     totalCount = rows.Count();
     MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
     model.marketingdbclients_dataTables = db.tbl_dataTable.OrderByDescending(r => r.ClientId).Where(r => r.UploadId == id).ToList().ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
     model.totalCount = totalCount ;
     return View(model);               

}
```

Then in your View (index.cshtml), declare MyViewModel like so:

```
@model WebApp.Models.MyViewModel

<div>
    your html
</div>
```

The concept we just used is called View Model. Please read more about it here:
[Understanding ViewModel](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/QHQT270712-Understanding-ViewModel-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html)

Answer (score 1):

You may only pass *one model object* when calling `View(model)`.

You can create an object that contains both the count and the datatable that you use as  the view model.

A simple way to do this may be using an anonymous object:

```
 return View(
  new {
    Page = db.tbl_dataTable.OrderByDescending(r => r.ClientId).Where(r => r.UploadId == id).ToList().ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize)db.tbl_dataTable.OrderByDescending(r => r.ClientId).Where(r => r.UploadId == id).ToList().ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize),
    Count = totalCount
 });
```